# Is it possible to Embed a Video in Email Newsletter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, video, html-email

I was wondering if I could send an email with video, where i can embed my wmv or any video files from my website on to a email so that when customers open the email they can click play and watch the video?

Or Can I include youtube video directly into email. So that the users can directly watch youtube video on their email?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on email client, but I've never met any mail client rendering Flash. This can be so because of several issues: security, licenses, render engine complexity that is avoided.

And [here's](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/entry/673/using-flash-in-email/) one good review on flash compatibility in all major mail clients.

Speaking of video stream files attached to the mail: you can do so, but you'll have to meet mail servers' size limits. And that's not a good idea to attach video, better add web link so that user can decide himself whether he wants this video or not. It's not good experience to have 7 Mb of unexpected mail traffic in newsletter :)

Answer (score 1):

you can integrate a video in your mail, it's more if you used with HTML5 
my proposition is to create an account on youtube and add your video,its so 
simple  to sharing it with Url
more instruction [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, use Adobe Indesign. Explore the options and you should find an "embed a video" option there. =)